# Why was my answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm truthfully perplexed at why [my answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222160/schemes-mechanisms-that-could-provide-one-time-decryption/222262?noredirect=1#comment453054_222262) was deleted by a mod. The down vote I understand, the deletion I don't.

A down vote is given when you disagree with the answer / you think the answer is of poor quality. A post is deleted only when the post has serious problems.

The reason given was

> this is not even close to an answer

I fail to see how. My answer is at the humorous side, but precisely answers the requirements of the question. It is a valid attempt to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"precisely answers the requirements of the question" -- except for the "data" part, of course.

As I said, it doesn't even work as an analogy.

Comment: `except for the "data" part, of course` - how? My answer clearly provides a scheme of representing data. It is not an analogy; it is a valid decryption scheme that fulfills the requirements, albeit impractical you may argue.

Comment: ... using ***food***

Comment: I'm not getting into how ridiculous this is and how you actually think this is valid enough of an answer to bring this up in meta, but if you meant this as a ***valid approach to consider*** it is such a poor solution to be simply "low quality". You do not address the "sampling a morsel" problem, smell, or the ability for the "taster" to compile the data once *each bit* is processed. And after all that, what you described is not "encryption" at all. It's "encoding". So, no. This is not a valid answer on any level.

Comment: Those are all reasons for down vote, not a deletion. FWIW, I did not even get a chance to edit the post based on your feedback. A post deletion happens if I post some offending text, or spam, or something totally irrelevant (e.g. pigs can fly). I still don't understand why the deletion was made so swiftly (and by a mod, without going through the review queue).

Comment: You have not described encryption. Therefore you missed the question entirely as well as being unimplimentable. So yes, deletion is warranted.

Comment: If you wish to post a new answer that is on topic, you are free to do so.

Comment: I respectfully disagree on not given the chance to improve my answer, but I accept your criticism on its content.

Comment: I do not understand why you do not see ***now*** as a chance to improve the answer. It is not like your post lost any votes. Edit the answer or post a new one.